# Data truncation: Incorrect date value

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

Tengo una tabla en `MySQL` llamada **registrologins**, diseñada de la siguiente manera en **SQL**:

```
CREATE TABLE registrologins (
    id_administrador INT NOT NULL,
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (id_administrador) REFERENCES administradores(id_administrador) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO registrologins (id_administrador, fecha) VALUES
(1, "2021/12/04");
```

Quiero registrar en esta tabla cada vez que un administrador se loguee en una app.

**Clase Registrologins:**

```
public class RegistroLogins {
    private int id_administrador;
    private Date fecha;
    ...
    public Date getFecha() {
        return fecha;
    }

    public void setFecha(Date fecha) {
        this.fecha = fecha;
    }
}
```

**Función fecha_sistema():**

```
    public static String fecha_sistema(){
        Calendar fecha = new GregorianCalendar();
        String ano = String.valueOf(fecha.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        String mes = String.valueOf(fecha.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        String dia = String.valueOf(fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        String f = ano+"/"+(mes+1)+"/"+dia;
        System.out.println("La fecha actual es: "+f);
        return f;
    }
```

En el evento `actionPerformed()` de `button` al loguearse, crearíamos una nueva fila en la tabla.

```
public static Date ParseFecha(String fecha){
    SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date fechaDate = null;
    try {
        fechaDate = formato.parse(fecha);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
    return fechaDate;
}
```

**Código a ejecutar en el evento actionPerformed():**

```
int id_administrador = Conexiones.saber_id_desde_administrador(administrador);
            
String fecha_sistema = Conexiones.fecha_sistema();
Date convertida_a_Date = ParseFecha(fecha_sistema);
RegistroLogins rl = new RegistroLogins(id_administrador, convertida_a_Date);
Conexiones.alta_registro(rl);
```

**Código alta_registro();**

```
public static void alta_registro(RegistroLogins registrologin) {
        String bbdd = Conexiones.bbdd;
        Connection c = (Connection) Conexiones.conexion_a_BBDD(bbdd);
        Statement stm;
        ResultSet rs;
        try {
            stm = c.createStatement();
            String insertar_registro = " INSERT INTO registrologins (id_administrador, fecha) VALUES "
                    + " ('" + registrologin.getId_administrador()+ "', '" + registrologin.getFecha() + "');";
            int resultado1 = 1;
            resultado1 = stm.executeUpdate(insertar_registro);
            if (resultado1 <= 0) {
                throw new SQLException();
            } else {
                //System.out.println("Registro agregado a la tabla registrologins.");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserción realizada con éxito.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                c.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Conexiones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

**¿Por qué me muestra el siguiente error?**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect date value: 'Fri Jan 28 00:00:00 CET 2022' for column `clientessl`.`registrologins`.`fecha` at row 1
```

Comment: 1. ¡Usá sentencias preparadas! Tu código es vulnerable a inyecciones SQL. 2. Tenés que _re-parsear_  la fecha, o crear un método en tu clase que te devuelva la fecha parseada.

Comment: @padaleiana Entiendo tu explicación pero ¿en qué falla mi código? Porque muestra ese error si estoy parseando la fecha.

Comment: @omaza1990 Lo que falla es que la fecha que le estás proporcionando a MySQL no la entiende, por eso en mi respuesta de abajo te he recomendado que utilices la función de MySQL en vez de enviarle tú la fecha desde Java.

Comment: Usa java.time y sentencias preparadas, notarás un código más limpio, ordenado y de paso soluciona tu problema de manejo de fechas para cualquier base datos.

Comment: @Joshin Gracias por la información. Trataré de realizar sentencias preparadas cambiando el código a 'INSERT INTO registrologins (id_administrador, fecha) VALUES (?, ?)");' ¿A esto se refiere?

Comment: Sí a eso me refiero y para el manejo de fechas java.time tiene la solución al problema de tu código, java.date y Calendar ya no debería usarse actualmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es guardar la fecha de cada registro por qué en vez de calcular la fecha en java no la calculas directamente en mysql con `NOW()`?

Así tu consulta quedaría así

```js
insertar_registro = " INSERT INTO registrologins (id_administrador, fecha) VALUES " + " ('" + registrologin.getId_administrador() + "', NOW());";`
```